# SQL Server 2014 Random Value in Group By

Tags: sql-server, random

I'm trying to figure out how to get a single random row returned per account from a table. The table has multiple rows per account or in some cases just a single row. I want to be able to get a random result back in my select so each day that I run the same statement I might get a different result.

This is basis of the query:

```
select number, phonenumber
from phones_master with(nolock)
where phonetypeid = '3'
```

This is a sample result set

```
number         phonenumber    
--------------------------
4130772,       6789100949    
4130772,       6789257988
4130774,       6784519098
4130775,       6786006874
```

The column called `Number` is the account. I'd like to return a single random row. So based on the sample result set above the query should return 3 rows.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm beating my head against the wall with this one.

Thanks

Comment: Why `WITH(NOLOCK)`? That means "read dirty data", not "don't take any locks". If you have locking issues, consider switching to SNAPSHOT ISOLATION

Answer (score 9):

You can use **WITH TIES** in concert with **Row_Number()**

```
Select Top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable
 Order by Row_Number() over (Partition By Number Order By NewID())
```

**Returns (for example)**

```
number  phonenumber
4130772 6789257988
4130774 6784519098
4130775 6786006874
```

Comment: `Top 1 with ties` I like that ;)

Comment: @Prdp Wish I could take credit for the concept, but I'm not that bright.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another table called `account` where those `number's` are generated/created then here is one way using `Cross Apply`.

```
SELECT at.number,
       cs.phonenumber
FROM   account_table at
       CROSS apply(SELECT TOP 1 phonenumber
                   FROM   phones_master pm
                   WHERE  at.number = pm.number
                          AND phonetypeid = '3'
                   ORDER  BY Newid()) cs (phonenumber)
```

Also this considers the `number` in `account` table is unique.

Creating a `Index` on `number` and `phonetypeid` in `phones_master` table should improve the performance